# Css customized list

Tags: html, css

I am looking to generate an expandable/collapsible list/ul using uss and html only like below
:
[image]

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Use image for each bulletin element.

Comment: You could refer to li:after and li:before to add pseudo element that you can customize how you want....

Comment: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/1427878)

Comment: @GicuAftene I tried that but wasn't that helpful, something like it can be found at https://codepen.io/bisserof/pen/nrMveb

Answer (score 2):

Hide default bullets and replace them with images.

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

li {
    position: relative;
}

li:before {
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    left: -40px;
    top: 0;
    background: url('https://i.ibb.co/gjc6V6D/Screenshot-2022-08-18-at-12-11-30.png') no-repeat center center;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 40px;
    height: 20px;
}

li:last-child:before {
    background-image: url('https://i.ibb.co/fXPLqd9/Screenshot-2022-08-18-at-12-17-47.png');
    left: -36px; /* not needed if images are same size */
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>A</li>
  <li>A</li>
  <li>A</li>
  <li>A</li>
  <li>A</li>
  <li>A</li>
  <li>A</li>
  <li>A</li>

</ul>
```

Comment: Isn't it possible to achieve this without static images? by using css only?

Comment: @MuhammadUmair With SVG maybe, or some fancy CSS with border radius and few overlapping divs, but I would not invest so much time in that